# Using SQLite with Windows Phone 7 development

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I am new for the Windows Phone 7 development and I am using SQLite as a database for this.

So can any one help me about how to use that.

If you have any help link or forum about this then please help me. I am searching this since 2 days but i m not getting about what i am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most preferable answer for this question is i got from

http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app/

and from

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/07/wp7-sqliteclient-with-transaction.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried searching for it on the internet?

[Here is an article](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/03/sqlite-for-wp-7-series-proof-of-concept.html) on that for example.

And here is a [search result with list of articles on Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=SQLite+with+Windows+Phone+7&go=&form=QBLH&qs=n&sk=).

Comment: By the way, these links aren't very useful any more. The first link is "invite only" and the first page of Bing is full of pages which reference your first link. Any ideas where I can find the information in the first link? I've tried the Way Back Machine.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite support on WP7 isn't as well established as some of the alternatives.

Unless you are particularly attached to SQLite, then I'd recommend trying something like http://sterling.codeplex.com/ which is build for C# and WP7 from the ground up.