# How to read a database file in WP7?

Tags: database, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a database file that I want to read its values from my WP7 application. I could see its contents from SQL-Lite Database Browser as in this picture:

[image]

Notes: 
1- there is no extension for this file.
2- I don't need to update its values.
3- If there's a way to convert it to another formula (xml for example).

Thanks.

Comment: Where should I send the bill? Or in other words, what have you tried?

Comment: Actually, I'm very good at Windows Phone, but this is my first database project. All tutorials that I read were about creating databases, but I have a pre-defined one!

Comment: What have you searched for in that case. You display a sqlite database, did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165026/using-sqlite-with-windows-phone-7-development for instance?

Comment: Now I found it. It was here:
 http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/01/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html
 Thanks.